# Is there string formatting function in Kusto?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I am struggling to find that in the list of [scalar functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalarfunctions). Is there something more convenient that `strcat()` for string formatting in Kusto?

Comment: I'm afraid not, unless what you need is to concatenate strings with a delimiter and then you can use strcat_delim https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/strcat-delimfunction

Comment: P.S. I assume you refer to something like Spark's `format_string` (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#format_string) or `printf` (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#printf)

Comment: Yes, I meant something like that.

Comment: I need formatting also.  Only in the browser UI.  Want numbers to loose the formatting that it added.  Adding ',' characters that I don't want.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments say, there is no such function today. Please do consider voting for one on https://aka.ms/adx.ideas.

Other thoughts:

- User the format_* functions for specific formatting like printing bytes, datetime etc.
- Use a python function to run the formatting